# How can I use grep and regular expression to display names with just 3 characters

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I am new to grep and UNIX. I have a sample of data and want to display all the first names that only contain three characters e.g. Lee_example.  but I having some difficulty doing that. I am currently using this code  `cat file.txt|grep -E "[A-Z][a-z]{2}"` but it is displaying all the names that contain at least 3 characters and not **only** 3 characters

Sample data

| name | number |
| --- | --- |
| Lee_example | 1 |
| Hector_exaple | 2 |

Comment: Do you want `grep -E '^[A-Z][a-z]{2}$'`?

Comment: thanks for the response. But it is not what I am looking for I would like it to just show names with 3 characters such as lee_example and not Hector_example.  As this code will show both

Comment: `grep -E '^[A-Z][a-z]{2}_'`? Could you precise the requirments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the `_` after the first name.

```
grep -E "[A-Z][a-z]{2}_"
```

Comment: note: [A-Z] will not work for non English names with umlauts. You should use `[[:upper:]]` and `[[:lower:]]`

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F_ 'length($1)==3{print $1}'
```

`-F_` tells awk to split the input lines by `_`. `length($1) == 3` checks whether the first fields (the name) is 3 characters long and `{print $1}` prints the name in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The following command can be tried out :

```
grep -w "..." file.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.